# how find the list of programs installed using the command line and how to get uninstall them

Tags: command-line

I have installed the ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS recently. I have used the terminal to install some music packages. But i dont no how many music packages that i have installed.So can any one help me with the commands used to find the list of packages install in the machine and how to uninstall it using command line.

Answer (score 1):

For a list of packages sent to a file: `dpkg -l > installed.txt`

To remove one of them: `sudo apt-get purge {}` where {} is the package name.